# I have a problem reading the information from a json file

Tags: python, json, pandas

I save data from the car's computer into a json file. (For example, engine revolutions per minute.)
My file json looks like this:

```
{"Clock": "17:37:42", "Value": 801.0}
{"Clock": "17:37:43", "Value": 791.0}
{"Clock": "17:37:45", "Value": 766.0}
{"Clock": "17:37:46", "Value": 788.0}
{"Clock": "17:37:47", "Value": 792.0}
....
```

I have to read this information and put it in a graph.
Can you give me a hand?I would be very grateful.

I use the python language with the specific libraries: tkinter, matplotlib, etc

My code portion looks like this:

```
def animate(i):
    data=[]
    with open('rpm.json') as f:
        data=json.dumps(f)

    data = pb.DataFrame(data)

    clock=data[(data['Ora']=='%H:%M:%S')]
    clock["datestamp"]=np.array(clock['%H:%M:%S']).astype("datetime64[s]")
    dateClock=(clock["datesteam"]).tolist()

    value = data[(data['Value'] == rpm.value.magnitude)]
    value["datestamp"] = np.array(value[rpm.value.magnitude]).astype("datetime64[s]")
    datevValue = (value["datesteam"]).tolist()

    a.clear()
    a.plot_date(dateClock, clock["Clock"])
    a.plot_date(dateValue, value["Value"])
```

Comment: Hi perhaps try https://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html

Comment: Is that what your json file actually looks like?  Because that's not valid json.

Comment: Try `json.load(f)`. The dumps function is for writing an object as a JSON string.

Comment: John Gordon, yeah, that's what the Json file looks

Comment: {"rpm":[{
                        "Clock": time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"),
                        "Value": rpm.value.magnitude
                    }]
                    }
it's OK like this?

Comment: The syntax of the individual dictionaries is fine; the problem is that they're separate objects in the file, which json doesn't allow.  It requires one (and only one) top-level object.  In this case, you'd probably want to enclose all the dicts in a list, i.e. `[ {}, {}, {} ]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Josh Gordon pointed out in the comments you do not have a valid json file. One solution would be to fix the format by enclosing the dicts as follows.

```
{"data":[
  {"Clock": "17:37:42", "Value": 801.0},
  {"Clock": "17:37:43", "Value": 791.0},
  {"Clock": "17:37:45", "Value": 766.0},
  {"Clock": "17:37:46", "Value": 788.0},
  {"Clock": "17:37:47", "Value": 792.0}
]}
```

Another option would be to parse the dictionaries one by one. If you want a pandas dataframe in the end, you could use `literal_eval` function from the `ast` module to read each line.

```
import ast

data = pd.DataFrame()
f = open('rpm.json')
for line in f:
    data = data.append(ast.literal_eval(line), ignore_index=True)
f.close()
```

You should get a dataframe as below and from there it should be easy to plot the graphs.

```
In [1]: data
Out[1]: 
   Clock     Value
0  17:37:42  801.0
1  17:37:43  791.0
2  17:37:45  766.0
3  17:37:46  788.0
4  17:37:47  792.0
```